# How to override Plugin javascript function : $('body').on('change','.class')

Tags: plugins, javascript, body-class

**EDITED: Extensively rewritten after some research**

**Requirement**

I need to override a script in the `custom.js` of a 3rd party plugin.

```
$('body').on('change', '.wpt_row input.input-text.qty.text', function() {
   (some javascript code here)
}`
```

**What I know so far**

I need to:

- dequeue the plugin script in

  - `/wp-content/plugins/3rd-party-plugin/assets/custom.js`
- and then enqueue my own script from

  - `/wp-content/themes/my-child-theme/includes/js/my_child_scripts.js`

To achieve this I must add something like this to my child theme `functions.php`:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_mod_script_load', 100);
function my_mod_script_load()
{
    wp_dequeue_script('THE_PLUGIN_SCRIPT');
    wp_enqueue_script('MY_MOD_SCRIPT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/scripts.js');
}
```

**Where I get stuck**

The script I want to override is an 'event based function', and not a 'named function'.

I am nor sure how to reference that in the dequeue and enqueue calls.

In the above, what would I use for:

**THE_PLUGIN_SCRIPT**

**MY_MOD_SCRIPT**

---

Thanks to @WebElaine for giving me a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: It depends on the plugin, but if the plugin has been coded properly, you should be able to find a call to `wp_enqueue_script()` that actually pulls the `custom.js` script onto the site. If that is the case, you can use `wp_dequeue_script()` to remove the plugin's script, and then `wp_enqueue_script()` to enqueue your own replacement JS file.

Comment: @WebElaine : Thanks. I did read up on this. Example link below. My shortcoming in mu understanding at the moment is how to reference the script or function. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45003932/how-to-override-contact-form-7-js-files-in-child-theme